# Slicing a list in Django template

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

If I want to get first 5 elements from a list I would do `mylist|slice:"5"`

but I want a range, let say from 3 to 7. something like `mylist[3:8]`  how would I do that in template

Answer (score 53, accepted):

you can just use

```
{{ mylist|slice:"3:8" }}
```

Answer (score 30):

Its simple you will have to **pass this in the slice** filter then:

```
{{ mylist|slice:"3:8" }}
```

This filter takes care of all type of slicing you can perform on a list

e.g. **All this would work**:

```
{{ mylist|slice:"3:8" }}

{{ mylist|slice:":2" }}

{{ mylist|slice:"3:" }}

{{ mylist|slice:":" }}
```

Comment: How to get the last nth element? Just like in python we can do `array[2:-1]`. `-1` do not work in django template language...

Comment: @RahatZaman Negative indexing isn't supported.